# Is there a way to see when iptables was last changed?

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to see when iptables was last changed?

I'm running CentOS5. I found this morning that the configuration is different from what I set 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way, but I use a custom chain to setup the iptables activation date, like so:

```
DATE_AND_TIME=`date +"%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S"`
iptables -N X_DATE_$DATE_AND_TIME
```

**Note:** I have started the custom chain with `x` to be the last chain.

To print the last activation date:

```
iptables -L -n -v | grep X_DATE
```

It will print something like:

```
Chain X_DATE_13-02-14_11-36-05 (0 references)
```